# Ninject Several constructors have the same priority

Tags: ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I can't get rid of the exception which comes from Ninject "Several constructors have the same priority"

I have repository

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    List<TEntity> FetchAll();
    IQueryable<TEntity> Query { get; }
    void Add(TEntity entity);
    void Delete(TEntity entity);
    void Save();
}


public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly DataContext _db;

    public Repository(DataContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    #region IRepository<T> Members

    public IQueryable<T> Query
    {
        get { return _db.GetTable<T>(); }
    }

    public List<T> FetchAll()
    {
        return Query.ToList();
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        _db.GetTable<T>().InsertOnSubmit(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        _db.GetTable<T>().DeleteOnSubmit(entity);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _db.SubmitChanges();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Controller where I am trying to bind repository

```
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IRepository<Store> _storeRepository;

 public AdminController(IRepository<Store> storeRepository)
        {
            _storeRepository = storeRepository;
        }

}
```

Ninject boot strapper

```
       private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    kernel.Bind(typeof (DataContext)).ToMethod(context => new DataContext(connectionString));
    kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>));
}
```

After I run app I get error

```
Error activating DataContext using implicit self-binding of DataContext
Several constructors have the same priority. Please specify the constructor using ToConstructor syntax or add an Inject attribute.

Constructors:
DataContext(string fileOrServerOrConnectionMappingSource mapping)
DataContext(IDbConnection connectionMappingSource mapping)
```

It seems that Ninject tries to bind to DataContext  class constructor

```
namespace System.Data.Linq: IDisposable
{
    public class DataContext : IDisposable
    {
        public DataContext(IDbConnection connection);
        public DataContext(string fileOrServerOrConnection);

//skip code


}
```

but I want to bind to my repository constructor

```
  public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly DataContext _db;

        public Repository(DataContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
//skip code
}
```

Also if I remove line below form boot strapper I still get the same exception. It seems Ninject automatically tries to bind dependencies when I am trying to bind Repository.

```
    kernel.Bind(typeof (DataContext)).ToMethod(context => new DataContext(connectionString));
```

Comment: Your code should work with the `kernel.Bind(typeof (DataContext)).ToMethod(context => new DataContext(connectionString));`... you should double check it. Also you should put a breakpoint on the line `kernel.Bind(typeof (DataContext)...` to check it is really executed.

Comment: It is executed and it do not work. Ninject tries to bind not only Repository Constructor but also DataContext Constructor.

Comment: Have you checked that there is only one kernel instance?